# How to find and iterate all iframe elements inside a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with some id and the div has some iframe elements. I need to find those iframe elements and iterate over them.

Currently I can get all iframe elements using following script.

```
$("iframe").each(
                 function(index, elem) {
                     elem.setAttribute("width","245");
                     elem.setAttribute("height","170");
                 }
            );
```

How do I get iframes inside a div with some id?

Answer (score 2):

Just add it to the selector:

```
$('#the_id iframe')
```

Or if you don't like long selectors:

```
$('#the_id').find('iframe')
```